# Using DriveApp class in Google Sheets template

Tags: google-apps-script, google-workspace

I've written a function in Apps Script that creates a new folder alongside the active spreadsheet, but I'm falling over when it comes to the trigger.

I gather that to be able to create folders you need to use an Installable Trigger rather than a Simple Trigger, but I'm trying to do this in a Google Sheets template file so I can't use the UI to install a trigger.

When I try to create the trigger programmatically I just get a *You do not have permission to call ScriptApp.newTrigger* error. This might be because the file is created from a template?
Is there a way to have that trigger automatically installed when the new spreadsheet is created from the template file, preferably without asking the user for authorisation first?

This will be built in G Suite and would only need to be used by our users. Is there a way in G Suite to install this trigger domain-wide?

Thanks

Comment: I have a small doubt regarding your question. When you talk about the template file, you mean a custom template you create, right?

Comment: It's a spreadsheet file that I've submitted to the Template Gallery.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand you correctly, you want users to be able to:

- Create a new Spreadsheet based on an existing template.
- Create folders using a function defined in the script (via [DriveApp.createFolder](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/drive/drive-app#createFolder(String)) I guess) without asking the user for authorization.

I'm afraid the authorization step cannot be avoided, but you can make the process less painful by creating a UI menu in the spreadsheet with a simple [onOpen](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers#onopene) trigger, which will have an item that, when clicked, will install your desired trigger.

I wrote a small example to show the workflow here:

First, create a simple `onOpen`, which will create a menu called `Custom menu` when the spreadsheet is opened:

```
function onOpen() {
  SpreadsheetApp.getUi()
  .createMenu('Custom menu')
  .addItem('Install trigger', 'createTrigger')
  .addToUi();
}
```

Then, if the user accesses that menu and clicks `Install trigger`, the following function will run, which will ask the user for authorization, and, when this is given, install an `onEdit` trigger:

```
function createTrigger() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  ScriptApp.newTrigger('createFoldersOnEdit')
    .forSpreadsheet(ss)
    .onEdit()
    .create();
}
```

Finally, the installed `onEdit` trigger will fire the a function called `createFoldersOnEdit` every time the spreadsheet is edited.

Comment: Hmm, I thought this might be the case. Thanks for the code.

So there isn't any way that as G Suite admin I could pre-approve the document? Or as a template the user only authorises once, and then the template is find to reuse?

Comment: Each different account (excluding Service Accounts) has to explicitly authorize APIs that will make changes to their files, there is no other way around it. That said, with a UI menu like the one I provided it's a matter of 2 or 3 clicks.

Comment: That makes sense, but what about with templates? It feels like once a user has approved a template once, as long as the access requirements do not change, it shouldn't need to be approved again.

I will look at doing this menu option though.

Thanks for your help.

Comment: Unfortunately, the fact that the file is coming from a template does not change this.

Comment: ok, thought as much. Thanks for your help, I may look at using the menu option instead then.

Comment: You're most welcome. Also, if the proposed workaround ends up proving useful, please consider [accepting the provided answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer), since this community relies on this to share knowledge to other users.